# Car won't crank, turn over, or start

Tags: starting

All the lights in my car work, but when I turn the key, you only hear the slightest click sound. That's it! Lately there's been a delay when trying to start it. I've had to hold the key turned longer. I need to get this fixed ASAP!

Comment: You really need to give us a little more information. The year/make/model/engine of the car would really help in the diagnosis. Also, I degraded all those caps down to regular type so it doesn't look like you're yelling at us.

Comment: Stop by an auto parts store and have them check your battery. It's possible the battery has capacity to turn all the lights on, but not enough to turn a starter.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check the starter/solonoid for operation. The electrical system must be checked for correct voltages from battery to starter motor. A quick and dirty thing you can do, as it seems to work intermittantly, is to give the starter motor a couple of firm clouts with a hammer and then try starting. If the starter is on its way out, this will cause it to operate again, especially if the problem is with the starters brushes sticking. Electrical checks before changing the starter/solonoid assembly though.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same behavior, then go to service and they repair my starter. It is cheap operation in my country (Belarus). You need to find service that can remove your starter and send to repairment.